# How to give transition effect on images overlay?

Tags: html, css, overlay, transition

Already I'm created an overlay on image background. but I couldn't add transition effect on that overlay. I want to give (transition: all .3s ease;) transition for overlay. Which will work for all h3,text and background overlay.

Thank you.

Sorry for my bad English.

The Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left
}
.floatright {
  float: right
}
.colum {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fix {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.header_area {
  background: #02918c;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.header {} .header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header a h1 span {
  color: #cfc91d;
}
.mainmenu {} .mainmenu ul {} .mainmenu ul#nav {} .mainmenu ul#nav li {
  display: inline
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a:hover {} .welcome_text_area {
  background: url(../img/bg-2.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / cover
}
.wel-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}
.welcome_text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 200px 0
}
.welcome_text h1 {
  font-size: 68px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 0;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}
.welcome_text h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.welcome_text p {
  font-size: 18px
}
.welcome_text a.know_more {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cfc91d;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #0b1016;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative
}
.welcome_text a.know_more:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "}";
  top: -145px;
  left: 90px;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.promo_area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.colum {} .promo {} .promo_title,
.work_title {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.promo_title h1,
.work_title h1 {
  color: #02918c;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative
}
.promo_title h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.promo_title p,
.work_title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  padding: 0 115px;
}
.promo_title p span {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #7e8287;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.promo_list {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}
.promo_list div:last-child {
  border-right: 0
}
.single_list {
  width: 290px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9dbdb
}
.single_list h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  margin: 34px 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.single_list p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.single_list img {} .service_area {
  background: #f0f0e8;
  position: relative
}
.rightimg {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/rightimg.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3
}
.leftarea {
  width: 590px
}
.service_list {
  padding: 60px 60px;
}
.service_list h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #02918c;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative
}
.service_list h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
}
.service_list p {
  padding: 35px 0
}
.service_item .ss_list {
  width: 295px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: left
}
.service_item .ss_list h3 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service_item .ss_list p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.service_item .ss_list img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.work_title h1 {
  text-align: center
}
.work_title p {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.work_area {
  margin: 0;
}
.work_slider{
    position: relative
}
.work_list {} 
.work_slider {
  width: 25%;
}
.work_slider img {
  width: 100%;
}

.work_slider:hover .slider_overlay,
.work_slider:hover .slider_detail h3,
.work_slider:hover .slider_detail p {display: block;}

.slider_detail {position: absolute; width: 100%;height: 100%; left: 0;top: 0;}
.slider_overlay {background: #1c9584; position: absolute; width: 80%; height: 80%; left:10%;top: 10%;opacity: .85;display: none; }
.slider_detail h3 {position: relative; z-index: 9999; color: #fff; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900; text-align: center;padding-top: 85px;display: none;}
.slider_detail p {position: relative; z-index: 9999; color: #fff; font-size: 13px; text-align: center;padding: 20px 70px;display: none;}
```

```html
 <div class="work_area">
            <div class="colum">
                <div class="mywork">
                    <div class="work_title fix">
                        <h1>MY WORK</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work_list fix">
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/230" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                        <p>onsectetur adipisicing elit, sedo eiusmod tempor incidi et dolorerserss eerhfre mag.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please only post the *relevant* parts of your code. What do you mean by " but I couldn't add transition effect"? `.classname { transition: 0.3s ease-out; }` would give you a transition effect.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I am new here. Can you tell me exact class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a transition to `display:none;` rules. You must change all of them to `opacity`, like follows. Take into account that here's only the code that has been changed:

```
.work_slider:hover .slider_detail h3,
.work_slider:hover .slider_detail p
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.work_slider:hover .slider_overlay
{
    opacity: .85;
}
.slider_overlay
{
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
.slider_detail h3
{
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
.slider_detail p
{
    transition: all .3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/9skyL8rk/